# Need help on creating checkboxes that filter content of an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, checkbox

I have just started learning html, javascript, and CSS and so I only understand the basics. For this class project I am working on, we have to create checkboxes that can filter out content of an array based on whether or not the strings in the array contain a certain letter. If they do contain the letter they will be removed from the array. 
My original array is an array called words

In my .html file i have the following:

```html
<form> 
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="A" onchange= "exclude()" /> Exclude words with 'A' <br /> </label>
            <label> <input type="checkbox" id="I" onchange= "exclude()" /> Exclude words with 'I' <br /> </label>
            <label> <input type="checkbox" id="O" onchange= "exclude()" /> Exclude words with 'O' <br /> </label>
```

and in my .js file i have :

```js
function exclude() {
    if (A.checked) {
        filterByLetter(words, "A")
    }
    if (I.checked) {
        filterByLetter(words, "I")
    }
    if (O.checked) {
        filterByLetter(words, "O")
    }
}

function filterByLetter(originalList, letter) {
    var newList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < originalList.length; i++){
        if (originalList[i].indexOf(letter) == -1) {
            newList.push(originalList[i]);
            
        }
    }
    
    par.innerHTML = newList;
    
}
```

When I run this code, it works, however, when I checked multiple checkboxes, only the most recent checkbox has effect. How can I make it so that multiple checkboxes being checked at once will filter out strings with all of the letters? And how would I do this so that if I uncheck the boxes at the end, the array will not be filtered by those letters?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `filterByLetter` function should return a filtered list like this:

```
function filterByLetter(originalList, letter) {
    var newList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < originalList.length; i++){
        if (originalList[i].indexOf(letter) == -1) {
            newList.push(originalList[i]);
        }
    }
    return newList;  
}
```

It is almost always better if your functions do only one thing, in this case filtering but not updating the HTML. Now you can apply it several times:

```
function exclude() {
    var filteredList = words.concat([]); // create a copy
    if (A.checked) {
        filteredList = filterByLetter(filteredList , "A")
    }
    if (I.checked) {
        filteredList = filterByLetter(filteredList , "I")
    }
    if (O.checked) {
        filteredList = filterByLetter(filteredList , "O")
    }

    par.innerHTML = filteredList;
}
```

**Bonus:** For the sake of more modern functional style you could write the `filterByLetter` function like this:

```
function filterByLetter(originalList, letter) {
    return originalList.filter(function(x) {
        return x.indexOf(letter) == -1;
    });
}
```